# How to invoke onChange for radio button using react-bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs, radio-button, onchange, react-bootstrap

I cannot find documentation on how to invoke onChange for radio buttons using react-bootstrap. I left out the button which submits the form. It works with every other field, like text inputs, so I left that out.

For each, teacherRate and overallRate, each radio button has a value of 1, 2, 3 but I am not sure how to tie that in.

I also know that I cannot have the values be the same for each category.

I am not looking to do Button Groups.

I looked online for similar answers but cannot find any. There was one person who posted their problem like mine but answered later saying he implemented react-bootstrap but did not post his solution. I cannot reply as I do not have enough points.

```
    class Assignment extends Component {

      constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          form: {
            teacherRate: '',
            overallRate: ''
          }
        }
      }

      handleChange(event){
        const formState = Object.assign({}, this.state.form)
        formState[event.target.name] = event.target.value
        this.setState({form: formState})
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <Grid>
            <form>

              <FormGroup>
                <ControlLabel id='adminRate'>Rate the Teacher</ControlLabel>
                  <Radio name='adminRate' type='integer' inline
                    onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
                    value={this.state.form.adminRate}>1</Radio>{' '}
                  <Radio name='adminRate' type='integer' inline
                    onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
                    value={this.state.form.adminRate}>2</Radio>{' '}
                  <Radio name='adminRate' type='integer' inline
                    onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
                    value={this.state.form.adminRate}>3</Radio>{' '}
              </FormGroup>

              <FormGroup>
                <ControlLabel id='adminRate'>Overall Rating</ControlLabel>
                  <Radio name='adminRate' type='integer' inline
                    onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
                    value={this.state.form.adminRate}>1</Radio>{' '}
                  <Radio name='adminRate' type='integer' inline
                    onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
                    value={this.state.form.adminRate}>2</Radio>{' '}
                  <Radio name='adminRate' type='integer' inline
                    onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
                    value={this.state.form.adminRate}>3</Radio>{' '}
              </FormGroup>
            </form>
          </Grid>
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The onChange event is being fired, but your handleChange function is not doing what you are expecting.

```
  handleChange(event){
    const formState = Object.assign({}, this.state.form)
    formState[event.target.name] = event.target.value
    this.setState({form: formState})
  }
```

If you take a look in a debugger, event.target does not have a name or value attribute for a check box. It simply has a checked attribute. You will have to find another way to get the information you are looking for out of the target.

Answer (score 1):

To piggyback off the previous poster, in your Radio buttons you have `value={this.state.form.adminRate}` but adminRate is never defined in

```
this.state = {
 form: {
 teacherRate: '',
 overallRate: ''
}
```

So when you return `formState[event.target.name] = event.target.value` from your handleChange function its not inputting any value into the `event.target.name`. So you may just want to input 1, 2, and 3 as the value in the corresponding buttons.

Also even if it did input values, `event.target.name` in your Radio buttons are adminRate so you'd run into the this.state problem again, so you'd have to convert `name={adminRate}` to `name={teacherRate}` in the first FormGroup buttons so that the formState object in

```
handleChange(event){
const formState = Object.assign({}, this.state.form)
formState[event.target.name] = event.target.value
this.setState({form: formState})
}
```

points to the teacherRate property inside the form object defined in this.state when you call `this.setState({form: formState})` at the end of the function.

I don't know the relevance of using the 'Overall Rating' radio buttons so I can't assist with the second FormGroup but it would basically be the same logic as the first. You'd need `Math` logic to get the average number for the overall rating though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `checked` attribute on the `<Radio>` element as a response to some state/props, the following is a snippet from a Formik / react-bootstrap form:

```
  <Radio
    name="upload_radio"
    checked={status.upload_radio === 'textarea'}
    value="textarea"
    onChange={e => setStatus({ upload_radio: e.target.value })}
  >
```